# asp.net mvc redirect to forms loginurl

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, redirect, membership

I'm my logout action method I'm trying to redirect to the loginurl as defined in the web.config.

I have tried

```
public ActionResult LogOff()
{
    if(Request.IsAuthenticated)
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();

    return RedirectToRoute(FormsAuthentication.LoginUrl);
}
```

However it returns an error

> A route named '/Home/Index' could not be found in the route
>   collection. Parameter name: name

The config setting is defined as follows

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="/Home/Index" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

Is there some other overload or method I should be using?

Comment: Instead of RedirectToRoute, have you tried just straight return Redirect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[RedirectToRoute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492497.aspx)(string routeName) accept a RouteName not a path.

Use RedirectToAction

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
```

Or [Redirect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirect.aspx)

```
return Redirect(FormsAuthentication.LoginUrl);
```